# python lxml can't find table

Tags: python, lxml

I am using Python 2.7 lxml and I am having problems finding the table.

Finding it by id od class produces null result.

```
 a = [c.text for c in kontent.xpath('//table[@id="blk-ctnt-2308"[1]//tr/td[5]]
```

Any other suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing square brackets in the XPath expression, before the index `[1]`:

```
a = [c.text for c in kontent.xpath('//table[@id="blk-ctnt-2308"][1]//tr/td[5]') ]
```

Also, you may want to check if the first part of the expression works `//table[@id="blk-ctnt-2308"][1]` before you try out the full one.

Finally, if the source table has an `id` attribute, the index `[1]` is redundant but should still work.

### Update

I can't use `lxml` on this machine, so I am using the ElementTree XML API in order to test the XPath, this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

html = '''<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table id="blk-ctnt-2308">
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td><td>4a</td><td>5a</td><td>6a</td></tr>
<tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td><td>3b</td><td>4b</td><td>5b</td><td>6b</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2c</td><td>3c</td><td>4c</td><td>5c</td><td>6c</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="blk-ctnt-2309">
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td><td>4a</td><td>5a</td><td>6a</td></tr>
<tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td><td>3b</td><td>4b</td><td>5b</td><td>6b</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2c</td><td>3c</td><td>4c</td><td>5c</td><td>6c</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>'''

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(html)
results = [ c.text
            for c in tree.findall('body/table[@id="blk-ctnt-2308"]//tr/td[5]') ]
print results
```

Produces this output:

```
['5a', '5b', '5c']
```

Comment: I tried 
a = [c.text for c in kontent.xpath('//table[@id="blk-ctnt-2308"]')] but still i get the null result. What am I missing here?

Comment: What I meant was that you try to see what is returned by `kontent.xpath('//table[@id="blk-ctnt-2308"]')` before you dig deeper into it... I doubt that you will get much out of it in the list comprehension. Is there a chance you can share the actual HTML you are trying to parse?

Comment: If you haven't solved it, try your code against this test data?